# Google Checkout and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, google-checkout

I am creating a website with a google checkout link that lets customers purchase a digital product. This digital product is a credit to their account on the site. Therefore, I need to know how to make the completion of a google checkout order change a field in my PHPMyAdmin database. I would very much appreciate your answers.

Comment: "PHPMyAdmin database"? I think you mean MySQL database.

Answer (score 4):

phpMyAdmin is merely an administration interface to a database called mySQL.

Consider working through a basic PHP / mySQL tutorial first to get a fundamental understanding how these things work - *especially* if you're programming things in connection with commercial activity.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610543/recommended-way-to-learn-php

However, a good and complete code sample that you *could* derive from can be found here:

- [Good tutorial on how to update your Mysql database with a PHP form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466975/good-tutorial-on-how-to-update-your-mysql-database-with-a-php-form)

Comment: +1 Also, it might be worth reading up on the API callback URL for Google Checkout. (See e.g. [here](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134463) and [here](https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70647))

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a web service on your server as described in the document [Implementing the Notification API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html). You can do whatever you want in your web service when you receive a notification, including updating your data base.