# Why does my output wont update when i hit the update button? any suggestions and codes about this?

Tags: php, database, datatable

Why does my output wont update what seems to be the problem? sorry im just new in php can someone help in this?and i want to make a search bar not a dropdown menu im so frustrated in this codes help please

```
Childs Name:<?php
    $name= mysql_query("select * from persons ORDER BY name");

echo '<select name="name" id="user" class="textfield1">';
 while($res= mysql_fetch_assoc($name))
{
echo '<option value="'.$res['id'].'">';
echo $res['name'];
echo'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
?>
</div>
<br />
<div style="margin-left: 97px;">information:
  <input name="name" type="text" value="" /></div>
<div style="margin-left: 127px; margin-top: 14px;"><input name="" type="submit" value="Update" /></div>
```

My table

```
<div class="content" id="registry"><br><br>
<table width="100%">
<tr class="head">
<th>Date of entry</th>

<th>Date of Baptisim</th>
<th>Name of the Child</th>

<th>Birthday</th>
<th>Mother</th>
<th>Father</th>
<th>Mother's Address</th>
<th>Father's Address</th>
<th>Current Address</th>
<th>Ninong/Ninang</th>

<th>Amount Paid</th>
<th>Priest</th>
</tr>
<?php

$sql=mysql_query("select * from persons ORDER BY name");
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$da=$row['da']; 
$entry=$row['entry'];
$name=$row['name'];

$bday=$row['bday'];
$mot=$row['mot'];
$fat=$row['fat'];
$motadd=$row['motadd'];
$fatadd=$row['fatadd'];
$ca=$row['ca'];
$nn=$row['nn'];
$paid=$row['paid'];
$priest=$row['priest'];
if($i%2)

{
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">
<?php } else { ?>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" bgcolor="#f2f2f2" class="edit_tr">
<?php } ?>
<td class="edit_td">
<span class="text"><?php echo $da; ?></span> 
</td>

<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $entry; ?></span>
</td>

<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $bday; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $mot; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $fat; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $motadd; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $fatadd; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $ca; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $nn; ?></span>
</td>

<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $paid; ?></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="text"><?php echo $priest; ?></span>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Are you actually running an UPDATE query anywhere?

Comment: i dont know sir my codes is kinda messed up im just new to php and i edit my codes and somehow it wont work anymore

Comment: None of your code actually does an `UPDATE` query, so your database never gets changed.

Comment: so thats the problem sir?? how to make an update query?can you give me an example? thanks in advance

Comment: <?php
include("db.php");
$proid=$_POST['name'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
mysql_query("UPDATE persons SET name='$name'
WHERE id='$proid'");
header("location: tableedit.php#page=editdata");
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is very strange to say the least, by the looks of it you have a submit input and a name input but this is not being submitted anywhere.. first you want a form to post to `example.php`

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then from `example.php` you would want to run an update query using the data from your form:

`$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET value = '{$value}' WHERE id = {$id}";`

i suggest you look up a tutorial on how to update using php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466975/good-tutorial-on-how-to-update-your-mysql-database-with-a-php-form)