# Update retrieved data

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there im in the process of making a page to approve and deny names in a database, I currently have it so it finds an pulls the pending requests im looking for now i wanna know how to update the row once i click approve or deny.

the values it needs to update is the NameState column to either ("approved") or ("REJECTED")

there can be any where from 1 to 100 names at a time.

Thanks Ryan

```
 $DB_HOST = "IP";
        $DB_USER = "user";
        $DB_PASS = "Pass";
        $DB_DTBS = "DB";
        mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.
        mysql_select_db($DB_DTBS) or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

        $search = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `NameState` = \'(\"PENDING")\'') or die(mysql_error()); 

        $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);


        if($match > 0){
            echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Current Name</th>
                    <th>Requested Name</th>
                    <th>Approve or Deny</th>
                    </tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['object_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['WishName'] . "</td>";
                echo '<td> <form method="post" action=<?php echo Approve:<input type="radio" value="Approve" name="name"> Deny:<input type="radio" value="Deny" name="name"><br /> </td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";

            echo '<input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"> </form>';

        } else {
            echo("No Names to Approve");
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: If you want to "update", then use just that [`UPDATE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx) along with `SET` and a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: ok so something like this "input type="radio" value="UPDATE TBL SET '("APPROVED")' WHERE WishNameState" name="name 

sorry i am very new to php MYSQL connections lol

Comment: Hell no. You do NOT put queries into elements and then send them to the server (or as GET, POST or COOKIE values), ESPECIALLY INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE. The query is to be constructed ON THE SERVER based on the parts provided (and only after being *validated* and *sanitized* properly) from your HTML-based fields. You need to learn basic programming principles.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be injecting SQL commands as radio button values, plus that's not the way it's done. See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/2466975/ and http://www.createafreewebsite.net/phpmysql/update.html - and Google "mysql update tutorial php" - good luck. Those are `mysql_` based, but you should be using [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/php

Comment: Thanks Guys ill let you know what i return with

Comment: [Check here](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Oklahoma-Leaks-Tens-of-Thousands-of-Social-Security-Numbers,-Other-Sensitive-Data.aspx) to see more about how bad an idea that is. `;)`