# How do I send HTML form data to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am building a webpage that inlcude entering data into a databse. I am successfully connecting to my database, and my insert query is working as far as it is adding rows into the database, but the form data is not getting pass across so the rows are being created ( I have seen them in phpmyadmin) but the data is empty.

I have two pages. One for displaying the form, and one that receive sthe form data and runs the sql query.

This is the data for the form webpage

```
<body>


<form action="insert.php" method=”post”>

Venue:
<input type="text" name = "venue">
<br>
Date:
<input type="text" name = "date">
<br>
Time:
<input type="text" name = "time">
<br>
Postcode:
<input type="text" name = "postcode">
<br>

<input type="submit" Value = "submit" name= "submit">

</form>
```

This is the code that I am using for entering the data. I have not included the connection code for the database as I am not having a problem with this.

```
$venue = $_POST['venue'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

$query = "INSERT into `event`(`eventVenue`, `eventDate`, `eventTime`,
`EventPostCode`) VALUES (  '$venue', '$date','$time', '$postcode' )";  


mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

<hr>

</body>
```

Db Connection:

```
$host="50.62.209.87"; // Host name 
$username="************"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="extras"; // Database name 
// Connect to server and select databse. 
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($dbconn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Comment: Show your connection code. It is relevant here.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You should use **mysqli_real_escape_string($value);** for validation before use sql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good tutorial on how to update your Mysql database with a PHP form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466975/good-tutorial-on-how-to-update-your-mysql-database-with-a-php-form)

Comment: @Mehmet prepared queries are even better

Comment: thanks for the input, I am aware of sql injection and will be looking at it after I have gpt oast this issue

Comment: $host="50.62.209.87"; // Host name
$username="************"; // Mysql username
$password="********"; // Mysql password
$db_name="extras"; // Database name


// Connect to server and select databse.
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($dbconn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");                    this is my connecttion codw which is iin my file that attempts the insert

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` say?

Comment: Can you remove the quotes around the table name and actual column names ?
`$query = "INSERT into event (eventVenue, eventDate, eventTime,
EventPostCode) VALUES (  '$venue', '$date','$time', '$postcode' )";`

Comment: @KacyRaye They're called "ticks" and are correct syntax (and even recommended)

Comment: mysqli_error($dbconn); gave me nothing

Comment: I was taught to use bacticks for database identifying and straight ticks for data

Comment: @JohnConde My mistake.  I haven't seen them used in a while so I forgot you could do that.

Comment: @user3519506 There's something you're not telling or showing us because the problem isn't with this code.

Comment: Why are there 2 html tags "
<hr>

</body>" in the php area?

Comment: I literally have two files: one that has a web form and nothing else ont, and one that has php script that connects to the db and tried to insert the data from the webform on the other page. The action for the webfrom is set for the phpscript page. I have nothing else I can show you

Comment: The html tage are just bad copy and pasting onto here, they are on the end of the form file before the </body>

Comment: By the way you are writing your connection, it seems that you are using a remote SQL server. Are you sure the ports are open?

Comment: Yeah I am uploaded to a remote server,  I am not sure, I am not experiennced in hp and sql so I am not sure what you mean. I am successfully reading data from the database via a php script so does this mean the port is open?

Comment: @user3519506 Yeah your ports are open then.  Echo the data to make sure it's being returned from the $_POST array.

Comment: Thankyou. I have tried echo $venue and echo $_POST['venue'] and niether seem to print anything on the screen. The values that are entered into the form are being attetched on the url of the insert php script

Comment: Sorted, it was basic HTML error, thankyou @JohnConde for your help

Comment: and @KacyRaye. it is much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the double quotes of your method post. use this instead

```
method="post"
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fight the problem in steps:

1. `echo $_POST` and see if each value is OK
2. `var_dump($query)` and see if all is OK with apices and quotes etc...
3. try without ` `

Comment: Thankyou. I have tried echo $venue and echo $_POST['venue'] and niether seem to print anything on the screen. The values that are entered into the form are being attetched on the url

Answer (score 0):

Using mysqli or PDO you can block sql injection like below, hope this will work for you. I used PDO.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO event (`eventVenue`, `eventDate`, `eventTime`,
`EventPostCode`) VALUES (  ':venue', ':date',':time', ':postcode' )";

$insert = $db -> prepare($query);
$insert -> execute(
 array(
    "venue" => $venue, "date" => $date, "time" => $time, "postcode" => $postcode)
  )
);
```

Comment: How does this solve their problem? You provide no explanation at all.

Comment: @JohnConde, people has already provided that there is an sql injection.

Comment: let's focus on how to make it work first, then discuss about sql injection.

Comment: @JohnConde it should work, codes are correct. I have already checked it.

Comment: But it doesn't solve their problem. Their problem was they were using funky quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Ensure the connection by using that IP. And since it is from HTML form, I suggest you to use `strip_tags` and `isset`. It looks it's no use for it but it works as I try in my local server.

```
$venue = isset($_POST['venue']);
$venue = strip_tags($venue);
$date =  isset($_POST['date']);
$venue = strip_tags($date );
$time =  isset($_POST['time']);
$venue = strip_tags($time );
$postcode =  isset($_POST['postcode']);
$venue = strip_tags($postcode );
```

That's it. Besides, you should also consider the prevention how to handle sql injection as suggested.

Comment: $venue = isset($_POST['venue']);
$venue = strip_tags($venue);

echo $venue; I tried this but the echo still produced nothing

Comment: @JeanGkol This definitely does **not** work. `isset()` returns a boolean value. So you are changing the value of the `$_POST` variable to `true` or `false`. That is definitely *not* what they want. I don't know how you tested this but it clearly was an invalid test.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that elements are sent as the default `form` method `GET` due to the mistake in `quotes` as "Mark Te" answer. However, If you want to void this or if you planning to receive data from `GET` such as those in links parameters beside reciving it from a form's `POST` method.

```
<a href="insert.php?venue=lorem&date=2015-12-20&time=12">Get Result</a>
```

It is better to use [**`$_REQUEST`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) instead of `$_POST`.